# Canonical embeddings of unitary groups $U(n-1) \to U(n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology

I'm learning about Chern classes, and came upon the ncatlab site https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chern+class. In the proof of Proposition 3.5, they state that any two of the canonical embeddings $U(n-1) \to U(n)$ differ by conjugation of an element of $U(n)$. Can anyone help me understand why this is true?

I've tried to look at some lower degrees to get a sense of what's going on. The two canonical embeddings $U(1) \to U(2)$ are easy to understand, but then it quickly gets more complicated. I don't know much about Lie Groups and that kind of stuff, so I would appreciate an answer not using this theory - or let me know if it is necessary.

Comment: The "two embeddings U(1)→U(2)" are in fact much more than two (conjugate one of them by the elements of U(2)...).

Comment: That is not what the nLab argument says; it refers only to two of the $n$ coordinate embeddings. This is a much easier statement.

Comment: Right, I should edit it. I meant the canonical embeddings - sorry for the confusion, and thanks for commenting.

Comment: The embeddings differ by a permutation of the standard orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$, and these permutations are unitary. So two such embeddings differ by conjugation by a permutation matrix (in fact a transposition).

Comment: I get it now, don't know why I was this confused. Thanks for helping me clarify!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with help from the comments above. Writing out the embeddings, it's easy to construct a matrix from elementary column operations that does what I wanted. It's a permutation of the standard orthononormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$, which is clearly unitary, and we're done.